# Create a reusable template which can be used on various pages

Tags: html, angular, angular-ng-if

In my angular 5 application, I need to do this on every HTML page

```
<span *ngIf="item.createTime; else notAvailable">
   &nbsp;{{item.createdTime | date:'medium'}}
</span>
```

and on the end of page create that template

```
<ng-template #notAvailable>
    <span class="text-muted f-12" [innerText]="'N/A'"></span>
</ng-template>
```

there is repeating the same line of code on every HTML page, so looking for any solution which helps me to create one common component/directive which has only #notAvailable content and can be used on every page with `*ngIf`?

earlier in angularJS, we can create a separate template file and will be used but in new angular, there is no HTML can be attached in the directive, so a bit confused how to do this?

someone, Please guide me how to achieve this and what need to write in the respective component and HTML?

Comment: Just my Dumb Vue self asking this question but are Components not the right thing for your use case?

Comment: there is one [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) which makes me more confuse  which one to use as there are many such as decorator `viewChild`, `ViewContainerRef`, `Templateref`, `viewRef`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a component ex.: CreatedTimeComponent
**created-time.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-created-time',
  templateUrl: './created-time.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./created-time.component.scss']
})
export class CreatedTimeComponent {
  Input()
  createdTime: Date;
}
```

**created-time.component.html**

```
<ng-container *ngIf="createdTime; else notAvailable">
  <span>
     &nbsp;{{createdTime | date:'medium'}}
  </span>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #notAvailable>
  <span class="text-muted f-12">N/A</span>
</ng-template>
```

**some-other.component.html**

```
<h2>My some other component<h2>
<app-created-time [createdTime]="item.createdTime"></app-created-time>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution but I think it would be `<span *ngIf="createTime; else notAvailable">` in  **created-time.component.html**

Comment: This solution fit on HTML text content  but I also want to add same date format on HTML attribute to `[attr.title]="<here>"` I could not achieve this using above solution.

Comment: @diEcho it's not clear to me what you want. Could you explain?

Comment: whenever there is Date object it will display the time with 'medium' format otherwise N/A. and this answer  does not fit into [innerHTML]

Comment: Thank you for the usage of `<ng-container>`