# How to point other components in the else part of *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-ng-if

With extension of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039918/create-a-reusable-template-which-can-be-used-on-various-pages), here are another scenario where I need to use a template in else part of `*ngIf`

Here is my current code where I am using loading spinner on each page until API response returns

```
   <ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading; else spinner">
         <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
            // form content 
         </form>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #spinner>
        <div class="fa-3x tc">
            <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

this way we have to write the same **#spinner** component on every page so I have created a component with the same content.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-display-loading',
    styles: [`.load__spinner { color: black; text-align: center; font-size: 30px;}`],
    template: `
        <ng-template>
            <div class="load__spinner"> <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i></div>
        </ng-template>
    `,
    preserveWhitespaces: true
})

export class DisplayLoadingComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log('display loading called');
    }
}
```

Now my question is how to use this `<app-display-loading>` component within ***ngIf**

or this may be not the right way. Kindly suggest how to do this.

Comment: https://twitter.com/yurzui/status/1057167356626132992

Comment: @yurzui this is something what I am looking for. Thank you. Interestingly it works on negative condition only

Comment: check this , it only works perfectly when condition hs negation .https://ng-run.com/edit/ddqs9cmO4Qq8E8xlg39r?layout=2&open=app

Comment: in HTML `<ng-container *ngIf="isLoading withLoading">` and in directive  `@Input() set ngIf(condition: boolean) { if (condition) {}` does not work perfectly but adding negation (!) on both HTML and directive make it work perfectly. why so?

Comment: That's how ngIf directive works. Check the sources https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/ede65dbede75b89ef759df780fadb6c2769d1133/packages/common/src/directives/ng_if.ts#L106

Comment: @yurzui will you please post an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular structural directive can help us to point other component in  the else part of ngIf directive.

All you need to do is to just create directive that will supplement built-in ngIf directive.

The final syntax should look like:

```html
<div *ngIf="model withLoading">
  Model
</div>
```

which is just a sugar for:

```html
<ng-template [ngIf]="model" [ngIfWithLoading]="null">
  <div>
      Model
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

And here is directive itself:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngIfWithLoading]',
})
export class LoadingDirective {
  @Input() set ngIf(val: any) {
    if (!val) {
      const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(LoadingComponent);
      this.vcRef.createComponent(factory)
    }
  };

  constructor(private vcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }
}
```

So as soon as model is false the directive above will place your `LoadingComponent` instead of model template.

Don't forget to include `LoadingComponent` into `entryComponents` array

**[Ng-run Example](https://ng-run.com/edit/NQjQLpRClM7rQeMVSulo?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

See also

- https://twitter.com/yurzui/status/1057167356626132992

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `ng-template` like:

```
<div *ngIf="test; else otherTest"></div>
<ng-template #otherTest>
  <app-display-loading></app-display-loading>
</ng-template>
```

**Update:**
If your are using Routing then this example is useful for you:

in your AppComponent you can subscribe navigation changes
when `NavigationStart` show your spinner, when `NavigationEnd` hide the spinner.

**AppModule:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navigation/navbar/navbar';
import { HomeComponent } from './views/home/home';
import { CategoriesComponent } from './views/categories/categories';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'categories', component: CategoriesComponent }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CategoriesComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**AppComponent:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationStart, Event, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})


export class AppComponent {
  timeout;
  routerChanged = true;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {

      if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        // Show spinner
        this.routerChanged = true;
      }

      if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // Hide spinner
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          clearTimeout(this.timeout);
          this.routerChanged = false;
        }, 1000);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**AppComponent Html:**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<div class="spinner" *ngIf="routerChanged"></div>
```

[**Here is a worked example:**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-spinner-example)

> And you don't need any more to repeat the same spinner html in all
>   your pages.

Comment: doing this approach we again writing the same template code into each HTML page which I do not want to

Comment: Are you using Routing?

Comment: what is the role of routing here?

Comment: @diEcho if your are using routing there is an other solution.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet but I already implement the same logic on page change. Here I need the API response waiting spinner on same page.

Comment: This will wait for the api response, It will be ended when the html completely loaded. I have this timeout, because I don't have any response, but you can remove it. Alternative you can use a service to connet to api, and each time you call the service make this variable false and make it true again in success.

Answer (score 0):

I am using something similar to `<app-display-loading>` all over the project and all I need to do is

```
<app-display-loading *ngIf="isLoading"></app-display-loading>
```

but first you need to add `DisplayLoadingComponent` class in the module in which the component is located like this

```
exports = [DisplayLoadingComponent]
declarations = [DisplayLoadingComponent]
```

Comment: by doing this ; I need to restructure my all forms and wrap over `<ng-template>`. I am using ng-container and nee to use in `*ngif`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!isLoading">
     <form [formGroup]="myForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
        // form content 
     </form>
</ng-container>

<app-display-loading *ngIf="isLoading"></app-display-loading>
```

set isLoading accordingly.and,
set prevent default inside submit()

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use HTTP interceptor for displaying spinner in every request.

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51813213/1506955). Might be helpful for you. and for conditioning the spinner you can use variable from common service.

Or you can use your loading component on higher level and by CSS you can show loading on whole page so you don't need else condition part.